# Watchify - Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, git, require, watchify

i need Node.js feature like `require()` function in my javascript code so i am using watchify, but it is still giving me error `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at jsfile.js:3` despite the fact that watchify bundles code and inspects into `bundle.js` file, everything would be much easier if i was testing on localhost but i have hosted my website in heroku and i do not know queue of commands, should i do git commands (`git add .` `git commit -m "commit"` `git push heroku master`) and then watchify (`npm run watch`) or first watchify and than git commands? or there is problem somewhere else?  here is my package.json code (part)

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node ilia.js",
  "watch": "npx watchify ./public/jsfile.js -o ./public/bundle.js"
},

"devDependencies": {
  "watchify": "^3.11.1"
}
```

and linking of javascript files (bundle.js, jsfile.js) in my html

```
<script src="jsfile.js"></script>
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

so what should i do?

Comment: You need to only run the output, not the untransformed input.

Comment: what do you mean? remove jsfile.js?

Comment: can you post an answer with more explanation please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Client on node: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059580/client-on-node-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined)

Comment: No this is other type question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watchify creates a bundle file that has all of your code with the `require()`s handled.

That does not make `require()` work in your original code; you should only include the bundle in your HTML page and not the original JS files.